# Unrecognized column name that I define

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have the SQL statement below and it works:

```
SELECT T1.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(T3.CTransaction) FROM GBTransaction T3 
        WHERE T3.CSite = 'Store' 
        and   T3.CTransactionType = 'Release' 
        and   T3.CReference = T1.CTransaction) as releasecount 
FROM   GBTransaction T1 
where  T1.CSite = 'Store' 
and    T1.CTransactionType = 'Layaway' 
and    T1.CStatus = 'Active' 
and    T1.CBalance <= 0 
order by T1.CBalance, T1.CDueDate, T1.CTransaction
```

Basically I'm determining if there is a reference record existing through `(SELECT COUNT(T3.CTransaction) FROM GBTransaction T3 WHERE T3.CSite = 'Store' and T3.CTransactionType = 'Release' and T3.CReference = T1.CTransaction) as releasecount`

But if I add another WHERE condition which is `AND releasecount > 0`, SQL Server says

> `Invalid column name releasecount`.

The final statement including the added WHERE condition is the one below:

```
SELECT  T1.*,
        (SELECT COUNT(T3.CTransaction) FROM GBTransaction T3 
         WHERE  T3.CSite = 'Store' 
         and    T3.CTransactionType = 'Release' 
         and    T3.CReference = T1.CTransaction) as releasecount 
FROM    GBTransaction T1 
where   T1.CSite = 'Store' 
and     T1.CTransactionType = 'Layaway' 
and     T1.CStatus = 'Active' 
and     T1.CBalance <= 0 
and     releasecount > 0 
order by T1.CBalance, T1.CDueDate, T1.CTransaction
```

I'm confused and have no idea why it doesn't work? Thank you so much.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't like aliasing like that; use a CTE perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use a "column alias" in the where clause of the same query. This isn't possible in SQL Server (and in many other databases). Without going into enormous detail, the clause order of `select` to `order by` is NOT the way the query is executed - which starts with the from & where clauses. So in the where clause (executed before the select clause) the column alias can't be referenced.

There is another way to execute that "correlated sub-query" using an "apply operator". Here we can use a `cross apply`. Two advantages of this approach are:

- it is generally faster than the approach in your original query, and
- because apply operators are part of the from clause you can include the column alias in the subsequent where clause.

```
    SELECT T1.*
        , oa.releasecount
    FROM GBTransaction T1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(T3.CTransaction) AS releasecount
        FROM GBTransaction T3
        WHERE T3.CSite = 'Store'
            AND T3.CTransactionType = 'Release'
            AND T3.CReference = T1.CTransaction
        ) oa
    WHERE T1.CSite = 'Store'
        AND T1.CTransactionType = 'Layaway'
        AND T1.CStatus = 'Active'
        AND T1.CBalance <= 0
        AND oa.releasecount > 0
    ORDER BY T1.CBalance
        , T1.CDueDate
        , T1.CTransaction1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution works! This is the first time I've heard about Cross Apply. I still don't know how to use it but I'm reading about it now. Thank you again.

Comment: There is also `outer apply` which is similar to a `left join` (`cross apply` is similar to `inner join`). Now you know about apply operators you may never have to use a "correlated subquery" in the select clause ever again.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-apply